# Can't see help center icon in contact page when using dark theme

Tags: bug, design, dark-mode, contact-form

In the [Contact page on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/contact), that's what I see: (dark theme used)

[image: invisible help center icon]

As you can see, the [image being used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UIqe.png) fits the light theme, not the dark theme so almost invisible.

Can the image please be changed to something that would be visible also in the dark theme, or even better use the same SVG already used in the top bar?

Comment: Have you tried turning the light on?

Comment: @CodyGray [yes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2rSk.png)! ;)

Comment: In the dark, all cats are grey? :D